# SQL Server how to sum max for specific category?

Tags: sql-server, group-by

Got a problem when constructing a analysis SQL using SQL Server

The raw data as below

```
GameID | UsrRegID | Score_User
281    | 1        | 1
281    | 1        | 2
281    | 1        | 3
282    | 1        | 0
282    | 1        | 0
282    | 1        | 1
283    | 1        | 2
283    | 1        | 3
```

Below is the expect output result:

```
Distinct_Count_GameID | UsrRegID | Score_User
3                     | 1        | 7
```

The logic for calculating the Score_user as below:

Sum(Max(Score_user) for each GemeID)

So the result need to be 3+1+3=7.

Can using the pure SQL to get the above expecting output?

Comment: Have you tried a query yet?

Answer (score 1):

I think we need to aggregate twice here.  One option uses `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT GameID, UsrRegID, Score_User,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY GameID, UsrRegID ORDER BY Score_User DESC) rn
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT
    UsrRegID,
    COUNT(DISTINCT GameID) AS Distinct_Count_GameID,
    SUM(Score_User) AS Score_User
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1
GROUP BY
    UsrRegID;
```

Comment: Hi Tim what if the `Score_User` is not an int column. Currently the Score_user I'm using `CASE` `WHEN` to get the value. For example `CASE Score WHEN 'A' THEN 0 WHEN 'B' THEN 1 WHEN 'C' THEN 2 ELSE 3 END AS Score_User`

Comment: @Ye.s You may join to a table to convert the letters to numbers, but I am reluctant to change my answer now because your original question is the same.

Answer (score 0):

First find maximum value of score for each `GameId` and `UsrRegID` and then find **`SUM()`** for the column, `Score_User` and group it by the columns, `GameID` and `UsrRegID` using **`GROUP BY`** clause.

**Query**

```
select count(distinct [t].[GameID]) as [GameID], [t].[UsrRegID], 
sum([t].[Score_User]) as [Score_User] from(
    select [GameID], [UsrRegID], max([Score_User]) as [Score_User]
    from [your_table_name]
    group by [GameID], [UsrRegID]
) as [t]
group by [t].[UsrRegID];
```

Or, give a row number based on the descending order of score value and group by `GameID` and `UsrRegID`. Then find the count of distinct GameId and sum of maximum score.

**Query**

```
;with cte as(
    select [rn] = row_number() over(
        partition by [GameID], [UsrRegID]
        order by [Score_User] desc
    ), *
    from [your_table_name]
)
select count(distinct [GameID]) as [GameID], [UsrRegID], 
sum([Score_User]) as [Score_User] from cte
where [rn] = 1
group by [UsrRegID];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do an aggregate of an aggregate on the same `SELECT`, you can chain them together with CTE or subqueries.

```
;WITH Maxs AS
(
    SELECT
        T.GameID,
        T.UsrRegID,
        MaxScore = MAX(T.Score_User)
    FROM
        YourTable AS T
    GROUP BY
        T.GameID,
        T.UsrRegID
)
SELECT
    M.UsrRegID,
    Distinct_Count_GameID = COUNT(DISTINCT(M.GameID)),
    Score_User = SUM(M.MaxScore)
FROM
    Maxs AS M
GROUP BY
    M.UsrRegID
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try like following.

```
SELECT Count(DISTINCT [rgameid]) Distinct_Count_GameID, 
       Count(DISTINCT [usrregid]) UsrRegID, 
       (SELECT Sum(M) 
        FROM   (SELECT Max([score_user]) M 
                FROM   [TableName] 
                GROUP  BY [rgameid])t) AS Score_User 
FROM   [TableName]
```

**<kbd>[DEMO](http://rextester.com/EGQKEL84078)</kbd>**

Comment: Hi PSK what if the `Score_User` is not an int column. Currently the Score_user I'm using CASE WHEN to get the value. For example `CASE Score WHEN 'A' THEN 0 WHEN 'B' THEN 1 WHEN 'C' THEN 2 ELSE 3 END AS Score_User`

Answer (score 0):

Aggregates and a COUNT(Distinct GameID):

```
declare @raw as table (GameID int, UsrRegID int, Score_user int)

insert into @raw values (281, 1, 1)
,(281, 1, 2)
,(281, 1, 3)
,(282, 1, 0)
,(282, 1, 0)
,(282, 1, 1)
,(283, 1, 2)
,(283, 1, 3)

select count(distinct GameID) as Distinct_Count_GameID, UsrRegID, sum(max_score_user) 
from
(
select GameID 
 , UsrRegID
 , max(score_user) as max_score_user
from @raw
group by GameID, UsrRegID
) a
group by a.UsrRegID
```